# Getting error with variance_ratio() function of R package 'codyn' ("One or more replicates consists of only a single species")

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the function `variance_ratio()` from the 'codyn' package to find whether two populations' abundances are positively or negatively correlated over time. The column I'm using for `species.var` isn't actually the species names; it's names for the two populations. For `replicate.var`, I am using a variable called "siteyear."

When I try to find the variance ratio, I'm getting the error message

> "Error in check_multispp(df, species.var, replicate.var): One or more replicates consists of only a single species; please remove these replicates prior to calculations."

I assume this error means that one of the "species" is not found at all in some of the replicates, making its abundance always zero. However, I checked and all the site-years have abundance >0 for both "species", for at least one time point. There are some time points where one population has 0 abundance, but I don't see why that should be an issue.

Comment: It's impossible to help without seeing (sample) data and code. Please edit your post to include *representative* and *minimal* sample data along with those parts of your code that reproduces the issue. Take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to understand what's required for a good reprex.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to create minimal sample data that would replicate the error, I managed to figure out the cause. There were some replicates in my data frame with only one value for `time.var` (the time series had just one time point). This was flagged by the function `check_multispp()`, which is supposed to check whether the time series has more than one species, but the error message was slightly misleading.